# Check if annotation is on a road (Objective - C)

Tags: objective-c, annotations, mapkit, cllocationmanager

I am creating an annotation which randomly appears in a certain     radius but I only want it to appear on a road. Is there a way I could use geo fencing or keep refreshing the location until the annotation appears on the road with Objective - C.

Thanks.